Apparent contradiction in NAND implementation of XOR function
As I was trying to interpret the XOR function using only NAND gates, I came to a contradiction when looking up what the result should look like:
Step 1:
The following circuit is an unmodified implementation of the XOR definition \$ x\oplus y = x'y + xy' \$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Step 2:
This circuit results from transforming the OR gate in Step 1 using De Morgan's theorem:

simulate this circuit
Step 3:
At this point I got stuck and looked up the NAND implementation of XOR:

simulate this circuit
Step 4:
Then I took the only differing part between steps 2 and 3 and compared them:

simulate this circuit
The reason I know the two subcircuits are non-equivalent is that in the former allows unequal outputs, whereas the latter doesn't.
What did I do wrong?

A NAND gate is not usually equivalent to two NOT gates, but in this circuit the way the outputs are used makes it equivalent.
You can simply write out the truth tables for the two circuits and see that they both implement the XOR function.
If you want to work it out from De Morgan's rules, you have \$\overline{xy} = \overline{x}+\overline{y}\$. So \$x(\overline{xy}) = x\overline{x}+x\overline{y}\$. But \$x\overline{x}\$ is always false, so \$x(\overline{xy}) = x\overline{y}\$.
In an IC design I'm not sure there's even any benefit to using this "optimization" since a NAND gate requires 2 PMOS and 2 NMOS transistors, just the same as two NOT gates.
In a discrete logic PCB design there might be some benefit because the number of IC pins is reduced --- but then you'd be even better off simply using an XOR chip. The only real reason to use this would be if you happen to have a spare NAND gate available and no NOT gates.

If you want to use an XOR gate to implement a quasi analog function such as a frequency-doubler using an RC delay at one input, then making the XOR gate from Schmitt-trigger NAND gates, such as the CD4093, will minimize the chance of any oscillations when the RC voltage slowly goes past the logic trip point.

For IC design, the typical 12 transistor approach has fewer transistors than both the four NAND and three NAND/two NOT circuits. It's basically the two NOT design with a bit of optimisation of the three NAND gates.

Thank you for your clear explanation and for adding real-life applications to your answer. It's very useful and appreciated.

In real life, also consider propagation delays (over temperature) and possible output transients.

Since the question provided the reasoning process, step by step, borrowing from it could provide a clearer view by mixing two of them:

With both inputs at 1, the output is forced to 0 (X=0). All the other combinations "open" the AND gates, allowing A and B to pass to the OR gate. This includes the situation with both inputs at 0 (which is the other one for which the output is 0 in the XOR logic).

For the XOR gate with NAND on the inputs, you can see it as:

an normal OR gate
with a NAND to defeat the inputs = 11 condition

Therefore you can't substitute independent NOTs for the leftmost NAND - it's a test on the combined inputs.

(image taken from the question)
Below is the circuit with LHS NAND removed for now, replaced with a 1, and the final NAND with inverted inputs replaced with its OR equivalent. You can see you have an OR gate.
So the LHS NAND is detecting the inputs = 11 condition and gating the following AND functions to LOW, before they drive the final OR. Using De Morgan's for equivalent gates gets you the all-NAND version.

